# sed doesn't replace a string when this is at the end of the line

Tags: sed

Why this works

```
sed -n '242p' /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py

        model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))


sed -i "242s/.decode('utf-8')//" /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py

sed -n '242p' /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py
        model_config = json.loads(model_config)
```

and this doesn´t

```
sed -n '3328p' /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py
        original_keras_version = f.attrs['keras_version'].decode('utf8')

sed -i "3328s/.decode('utf-8')//"  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py

sed -n '3328p' /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py
        original_keras_version = f.attrs['keras_version'].decode('utf8')
```

Why I cannot delete the second `.decode('utf8')`. It is because it is at the end of the string.

I could another approach but I would like to be consistent with the code. I don't get any errors so I don't know what to do although I have been working around and looking for the answer on Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an important one character difference:

```
utf8
utf-8
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I miss that. And this also explain previous problems I got. Thanks!!